# first iphone app crashing for unknown reason

Tags: iphone, crash, logging, 3g

hi my app is crashing for no reason, it works very well on simulator however on IPhone 3g it crashes often. please help! below is the crash log from organizer window.

```
Incident Identifier: FE1D3406-8138-48E7-A107-62CA8346196F
CrashReporter Key:   896b2dc2588b18c140389cba404a81a4451a703c
Hardware Model:      iPhone1,2
Process:         Assistant [2521]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/D22CFF35-98CE-4955-8A66-7C7BC615766B/Assistant.app/Assistant
Identifier:      Assistant
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-02-07 07:38:52.213 +1100
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2.1 (8C148)
Report Version:  104
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib             0x32d25ad0 __kill + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib             0x32d25abe kill + 4
2   libSystem.B.dylib             0x32d25ab2 raise + 10
3   libSystem.B.dylib             0x32d3cd5e abort + 54
4   libstdc++.6.dylib             0x3582fa00 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 588
5   libobjc.A.dylib               0x301888d8 _objc_terminate + 160
6   libstdc++.6.dylib             0x3582d100 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 76
7   libstdc++.6.dylib             0x3582d178 std::terminate() + 16
8   libstdc++.6.dylib             0x3582d2a0 __cxa_throw + 100
9   libobjc.A.dylib               0x30186f28 objc_exception_throw + 104
10  CoreData                      0x33d2258a +[NSEntityDescription entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:] + 122
11  Assistant                     0x00004812 0x1000 + 14354
12  Assistant                     0x0000476e 0x1000 + 14190
13  UIKit                         0x3387f65c -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 824
14  UIKit                         0x3387f288 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 256
15  UIKit                         0x3386ec44 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 904
16  UIKit                         0x3386e8a8 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 36
17  Assistant                     0x00003aae 0x1000 + 10926
18  UIKit                         0x338a3f4c -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 884
19  UIKit                         0x339a5a9c -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 196
20  Foundation                    0x33fd44d4 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 360
21  CoreFoundation                0x35ebd2fe __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 10
22  CoreFoundation                0x35ebccd2 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 982
23  CoreFoundation                0x35e8ca8a __CFRunLoopRun + 1178
24  CoreFoundation                0x35e8c504 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 220
25  CoreFoundation                0x35e8c412 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 54
26  GraphicsServices              0x35261d1c GSEventRunModal + 188
27  UIKit                         0x33865574 -[UIApplication _run] + 580
28  UIKit                         0x33862550 UIApplicationMain + 964
29  Assistant                     0x00002f7a 0x1000 + 8058
30  Assistant                     0x00002f44 0x1000 + 8004

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib             0x32cd1974 kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib             0x32da02fc _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 88
2   libSystem.B.dylib             0x32d9fd68 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 96
3   libSystem.B.dylib             0x32d9f788 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
4   libSystem.B.dylib             0x32d28970 _pthread_wqthread + 392
5   libSystem.B.dylib             0x32d1f2fc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib             0x32c9d3b0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib             0x32c9f894 mach_msg + 60
2   CoreFoundation                0x35e8cf7c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                0x35e8c780 __CFRunLoopRun + 400
4   CoreFoundation                0x35e8c504 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 220
5   CoreFoundation                0x35e8c412 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 54
6   WebCore                       0x369e7d14 RunWebThread(void*) + 524
7   libSystem.B.dylib             0x32d27b44 _pthread_start + 364
8   libSystem.B.dylib             0x32d197a4 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib             0x32c9d3b0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib             0x32c9f894 mach_msg + 60
2   CoreFoundation                0x35e8cf7c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                0x35e8c780 __CFRunLoopRun + 400
4   CoreFoundation                0x35e8c504 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 220
5   CoreFoundation                0x35e8c412 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 54
6   Foundation                    0x33fe0c4e +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 210
7   Foundation                    0x33fbeb8a -[NSThread main] + 42
8   Foundation                    0x33fb7b90 __NSThread__main__ + 908
9   libSystem.B.dylib             0x32d27b44 _pthread_start + 364
10  libSystem.B.dylib             0x32d197a4 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib             0x32cc68d8 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                0x35ec5a34 __CFSocketManager + 356
2   libSystem.B.dylib             0x32d27b44 _pthread_start + 364
3   libSystem.B.dylib             0x32d197a4 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib             0x32d292fc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib             0x32d28b50 _pthread_wqthread + 872
2   libSystem.B.dylib             0x32d1f2fc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x3e74f308
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x04e8b02c      r6: 0x3eb9d4b8      r7: 0x2fdfe6a0
    r8: 0x35cf73a2    r9: 0x0000000a     r10: 0x3eba55a8     r11: 0x0003abd4
    ip: 0x00000025    sp: 0x2fdfe6a0      lr: 0x35de3ac5      pc: 0x35de3ad0
  cpsr: 0x000f0010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x38fff +Assistant armv6  <fc31e976a122d37eb046ec298ba2fdd6> /var/mobile/Applications/D22CFF35-98CE-4955-8A66-7C7BC615766B/Assistant.app/Assistant
   0xfa000 -    0xfbfff  dns.so armv6  <88b569311cca4a9593b2d670051860d1> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe29fff  dyld armv6  <617f6daf4103547c47a8407a2e0b90de> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30270000 - 0x3027bfff  ITSync armv6  <a451205e89373cbdf0832688085e8f72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x3027c000 - 0x3027efff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv6  <f42bbbf67195a7b98d67ad021bba4784> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x3027f000 - 0x3038dfff  CFNetwork armv6  <d6eeee83216ee9c553134f069f37cbc2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x303ef000 - 0x303f4fff  CaptiveNetwork armv6  <f41df4b358b77b29ff85e0eaea88ee1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x303f5000 - 0x30444fff  Security armv6  <cf625b4dc7ea928891313444ef64a7cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x30445000 - 0x3055cfff  libicucore.A.dylib armv6  <8968ff3f62d7780bb1bd75026a7628d0> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3055d000 - 0x30561fff  ApplePushService armv6  <0560b630d26e261e205fc58942e1885c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x3059d000 - 0x305a8fff  MobileWiFi armv6  <c7532e63e083a1dd2a0ef7352b85749d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x305aa000 - 0x30612fff  libvDSP.dylib armv6  <9d264733fc675943c082bd3b9b567b59> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x30613000 - 0x3064dfff  MobileCoreServices armv6  <beb473ce80390554bb4af21554522286> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x3065c000 - 0x3066efff  libbsm.0.dylib armv6  <51e7bb18da9afa44a33e54e42fbd0707> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x3066f000 - 0x306c6fff  CoreMedia armv6  <cd5e9398c161f129146931e888e1c92e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x306f0000 - 0x306fefff  libz.1.dylib armv6  <84592e96bae1a661374b0f9a5d03a3a0> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x306ff000 - 0x30729fff  PrintKit armv6  <74f9710fa01a33b5bb04c4aeabd6be7d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x307d7000 - 0x3082afff  IOKit armv6  <20da5e822f21a8d0a7c5b3e149330efd> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x30831000 - 0x3083bfff  AccountSettings armv6  <eca67ab04f724e1fa7c6406c88e75433> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x30999000 - 0x309c5fff  DataAccess armv6  <8c045822d57a369835f5b40653a48838> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x309c6000 - 0x309f4fff  MIME armv6  <fac8f55c508ff476e07894af7abdb761> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x30a04000 - 0x30aa3fff  ProofReader armv6  <2734920b62f174c17aeeb15f371615ef> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x30ad6000 - 0x30b1afff  AddressBook armv6  <1f30c3370dad27331a491ba4b190813c> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x30b3d000 - 0x30b9cfff  CoreAudio armv6  <ccc4bace0d6eca79a32ed84d566f72e9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x30ba6000 - 0x32ce3fff  TextInput armv6  <3fa14e6e5749e0230becd6ea34a8da7a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x32d7d000 - 0x32d89fff  libkxld.dylib armv6  <f74f359de7bbe3ccdc37fa6f332aebf4> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x32d95000 - 0x32e5cfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv6  <429841269f8bcecd4ba3264a8725dad6> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x32e5d000 - 0x32ecdfff  libsqlite3.dylib armv6  <87b9bb47687902d9120d03d1da9eb9fc> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x32f0c000 - 0x32f1ffff  libmis.dylib armv6  <dba9c086b49bd9540930ff27211570d6> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x33055000 - 0x33061fff  SpringBoardServices armv6  <fd0c472436b3306f5b56118c93c8a423> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x33062000 - 0x3306ffff  MobileBluetooth armv6  <2b68516e1321011a4efbee2947d463c6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x33070000 - 0x338bffff  WebCore armv6  <aa3b6827f051da7a3494c9bee4ebe290> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x338c0000 - 0x338d4fff  MobileDeviceLink armv6  <19d66078f8cf19be558713c13612c7a3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x338d5000 - 0x33a1dfff  libmecabra.dylib armv6  <fc962eeb4e6cfe4ad5ebee6fb4b1d5c1> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x33a6b000 - 0x33ab3fff  iCalendar armv6  <fbb717874ea0ede24454a5def644ab69> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x33ab4000 - 0x33ab4fff  Accelerate armv6  <cdde24a7ad004b2b2e600cd4f3ac5eb7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x33b32000 - 0x33b72fff  QuickLook armv6  <54400e0d48ec86c84e937e55790b9e54> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x33bbc000 - 0x33c0afff  CoreText armv6  <16c9582fdffb598178287c6ce9fd6897> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x33c16000 - 0x33d73fff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv6  <aec6b54ffd532bb607aab4acbab679b6> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x33d76000 - 0x33d79fff  ActorKit armv6  <d3ec50b4a7f0257ef31baf37936dc275> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x33d85000 - 0x33e71fff  QuartzCore armv6  <77cd91ff21fe6c58c309f2c82eb95ca5> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x33e72000 - 0x33e81fff  GraphicsServices armv6  <af20aba0ec96e7b7c42bb55ac763c784> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x33ead000 - 0x33f6efff  ImageIO armv6  <0c1b6f466667ff345f2399d8142a9d10> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x33f6f000 - 0x33f77fff  WebUI armv6  <1e0b1d9823fc1a56b2c4fa5c9027dc32> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebUI.framework/WebUI
0x33f78000 - 0x33f79fff  CoreSurface armv6  <5e290514380c626e9b0f9f9985b9dc7a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x340ac000 - 0x340bffff  Notes armv6  <acf9e548948ecb299270c8398ef297a1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x34137000 - 0x34156fff  EAP8021X armv6  <fa56845b5396c3ebb368c2368331643c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x341ad000 - 0x341ebfff  ContentIndex armv6  <7f3334380acc72292571803f0b490189> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x343a0000 - 0x343bffff  Bom armv6  <f41bef81e23e2bff59155e5ce46762d3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x343c0000 - 0x344bdfff  JavaScriptCore armv6  <3547c92c1efc0522b087e7f10eba7728> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x344be000 - 0x34500fff  ManagedConfiguration armv6  <397723a33c19c3487d304d69580acbfc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x34954000 - 0x34a5cfff  CoreData armv6  <6e3af4b4648ae695f8d4bc0bf5a9dba5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x34a6e000 - 0x34a72fff  CertUI armv6  <57c499baf9d343a78fe1b43f0f3ef997> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x34b18000 - 0x34b29fff  DataDetectorsUI armv6  <bec77a9774f3807e7c2e110780af1342> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
0x34b52000 - 0x34f1ffff  libLAPACK.dylib armv6  <0eb734c91165416224b98c943ff6476b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x34f20000 - 0x35014fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv6  <01916d6784f4de8f3746978faae9c5fa> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x35015000 - 0x35022fff  CoreVideo armv6  <7b100fd5fdf98db1cd0f0649e7f6f316> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x35023000 - 0x3507dfff  MessageUI armv6  <21bb9d93911f7015b79aef9dc6df55ef> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x35087000 - 0x35148fff  AddressBookUI armv6  <fea72732451610277e22a667d35ad76d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x35151000 - 0x35272fff  Foundation armv6  <6bdeb19a1fcb93e2930dadb50416f881> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x3529b000 - 0x352a6fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv6  <6aa8a4ed0906a495d059ace9125f525d> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x352dc000 - 0x35342fff  libBLAS.dylib armv6  <11a3677a08175a30df1b3d66d7e0951a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x35406000 - 0x35406fff  vecLib armv6  <8f914b3e8a581d49fb21d2c0ff75be03> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x35407000 - 0x3540afff  MobileInstallation armv6  <456ed7fe6dd9fcd8e78df425085b1452> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x35541000 - 0x35547fff  MBX2D armv6  <fad4955cab36e0179df6f8f27d365b8f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MBX2D.framework/MBX2D
0x35758000 - 0x35778fff  AppleAccount armv6  <0ef3f6564414f3ef030031ae25b28bbd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x35815000 - 0x3581afff  AssetsLibraryServices armv6  <224b3cf992a01814f91481244e3213eb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x3581b000 - 0x35877fff  libGLImage.dylib armv6  <7c1049f20c4e64591c09d3ac00c7d3ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x358bc000 - 0x358c3fff  liblockdown.dylib armv6  <f470dea180ddf23886df75eb256d3888> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x358cc000 - 0x358cffff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv6  <bed95ed187350ce27d22ed241ef892ea> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x358d3000 - 0x35d4ffff  UIKit armv6  <14ec6c926b8bda71b73136f6e1a6ac1b> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x35d5a000 - 0x35e98fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv6  <70571c1e697e2ae7f7a9b1a499453bb6> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x35f7e000 - 0x35fc2fff  VideoToolbox armv6  <101dbbcd34cc3231a8be3fd6392556aa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x35fc3000 - 0x35fd1fff  DataDetectorsCore armv6  <d19d233a6522749e0a169a89dd513cfb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x35fdb000 - 0x36162fff  CoreGraphics armv6  <9a1d72fa9549d83abc1e735ba37a4dc2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x36167000 - 0x36178fff  DataAccessExpress armv6  <c112bd2791eb706526db25407ec117d4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x36179000 - 0x36255fff  WebKit armv6  <83da207070be989ba81dba3a83d5206a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x36269000 - 0x36278fff  OpenGLES armv6  <37eda5ddcff210dd321157da35a87a5e> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x363f3000 - 0x363f9fff  MobileKeyBag armv6  <2d83bf6a43bab972d77a1a6e0f3b03d2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x363fa000 - 0x36483fff  Message armv6  <9ed4944d998f99e69ba81afdda659bee> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x365db000 - 0x365f9fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv6  <9c94634beea733e754dc115737b6e63c> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x36631000 - 0x36745fff  RawCamera armv6  <a431d55459002236dc9954046ee62900> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x36746000 - 0x3683cfff  libxml2.2.dylib armv6  <9c44d05cc67f1ebabd795903e581724e> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x3683e000 - 0x36888fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv6  <cfc94cfa17958f2f94c9eff208a7dace> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x36889000 - 0x368b4fff  MobileSync armv6  <b42cf746d993e6765d432edf47987835> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x368b5000 - 0x3692dfff  EventKit armv6  <c1fb82d645d3bf1f2e0558cc884712e9> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x3694c000 - 0x3694ffff  libAccessibility.dylib armv6  <74e0f77cc276a9412be268c795fdcbca> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x36955000 - 0x36a1ffff  Celestial armv6  <11172a6ee53bdf067548cd4496bc5fe0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x36a20000 - 0x36a2cfff  WebBookmarks armv6  <5d1eb10d851d0362e304d9d95f016df1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x36a2d000 - 0x36a30fff  CrashReporterSupport armv6  <00bc60f690e6328b64e7a7b718edf45a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x36a31000 - 0x36a74fff  CoreTelephony armv6  <cabbce0fa7630065dc7e7d3ca3bc616c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x36c1c000 - 0x36c26fff  AggregateDictionary armv6  <f7429444c955e4f13c6761d20032ab52> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x36c2b000 - 0x36de1fff  AudioToolbox armv6  <bb65e8ed531fe5923eb8ac00a7c0d87d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x36de2000 - 0x36e16fff  AppSupport armv6  <783e14db9585fd063c0c2a755cd121b6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x36e17000 - 0x36e2dfff  PersistentConnection armv6  <006723906b8ac250c1681a1821fbe94d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x37141000 - 0x37184fff  SystemConfiguration armv6  <207f362e707871e74a292cfd1ea7893d> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x372aa000 - 0x37477fff  MediaToolbox armv6  <21ceabd0e5de17ad4e883c85fcd34d51> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x37478000 - 0x3747dfff  IOSurface armv6  <ffd66ca04dfe7d382d6961f0df3839ff> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x3748d000 - 0x374f8fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv6  <eccd1d7183e73587b2c0aa5755a19c39> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x374f9000 - 0x375e4fff  CoreFoundation armv6  <ab0eac0ddd5b4ae1bf8541116e3c0bd1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x3760a000 - 0x3760bfff  DataMigration armv6  <d2de7c0db77278484236669c2cdccabb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x37731000 - 0x37736fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv6  <bd1c480607cc286288db1ca1aec64180> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x377f6000 - 0x37817fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv6  <22c6da37f3adf325f99c3a0494e04c02> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x37992000 - 0x37999fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv6  <de9b417e7278742e90b30b1ad45f31fa> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have changed your Core Data model and you are accessing a previous version of the .sqlite file (you can fix this by removing your app from the simulator or phone and reinstalling, or "Reset Content and Settings" from the simulator menu)?

Otherwise, it's a good idea to do an Analyzer build (Option-I in Xcode 4, shift-option-A in 3) and check the issues reported. It doesn't look like an over-released object (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) this time but it is worth checking. When something crashes on the device but not the simulator very often it is related to memory, the simulator is far more tolerant.

You might like to check out [TN2239: iOS Debugging Magic](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2239/_index.html) also.

Answer (score 0):

```
10 CoreData 0x33d2258a +[NSEntityDescription entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:] + 122
```

Something seems to go wrong when you try and fetch an entity from CoreData. I suggest you start looking into that.

Comment: i am just opening a previous view and it actually works well most of the times. it crashes when i open a website in a webview and then pop a previous viewController after webview is done loading(this too only sometimes it crashes). if anything wrong with ManagedObjectContext then why does it break sometimes only.? please help –

Answer (score 0):

Does this line help you any?

```
10 CoreData 0x33d2258a +[NSEntityDescription entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:] + 122
```

Comment: i am just opening a previous view and it actually works well most of the times. it crashes when i open a website in a webview and then pop a previous viewController after webview is done loading(this too only sometimes it crashes). if anything wrong with ManagedObjectContext then why does it break sometimes only.? please help